# Java newbie needs help in database connection

Tags: java, mysql, connection-string, database-connection

I'm new to Java and even newer to java database connections. I've managed to create a database connection and query a table when I put it in the Main class. Now that I've moved it into a new class called Connection I am getting errors:

```
package lokate;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Connection {

private static Statement stmt = null;
private static ResultSet rs = null;
private static Connection con = null;

public Connection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Lokate?" +
                               "user=root&password=";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        retriveData("SELECT * FROM Users");
        int rowsEffected = 0;
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ sqlEx.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classEx) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ classEx.toString());
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ Ex.toString());
    }
}

public static void retriveData(String SQL) throws Exception {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("fname") + " : " + rs.getString("lname"));
    }
}

}
```

I'm getting an error saying cannot find symbol. Symbol:method createStatement() and incomparable types for con = DriveManager.....

Can anyone help?

Also, is it best practice to put the connection in the class like this then call a new object every time I want to do something with the db?

Regards,

Billy

Comment: all abt JDBC connection is here, http://www.codinguide.com/2010/04/prepared-statement-sql-injection-proof.html Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say your code is an example of many worst practices.  Let me count the ways:

1. Your Connection class is a poor abstraction that offers nothing over and above that of java.sql.Connection.
2. If you use your class, you'll never get to take advantage of connection pooling.
3. You hard wire your driver class, your connection URL, etc.  You can't change it without editing and recompiling.  A better solution would be to externalize such things.
4. Printing an error message in the catch blocks is far less information than supplying the entire stack trace.
5. Your code hurts my eyes.  It doesn't follow the Sun Java coding standards.
6. Your `retrieveData` method is utterly worthless.  What will you do with all those printed statements?  Wouldn't it be better to load them into a data structure or object so the rest of your code might use that information?
7. It's `rowsAffected` - "affect" is the verb, "effect" is the noun.  Another variable that's not doing any good.

You're on the wrong track.  Rethink it.

I think you'll find this code more helpful.

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DatabaseUtils
{
    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName(driver);

        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0))
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        }
        else
        {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st)
    {
        try
        {
            if (st != null)
            {
                st.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)
                    {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful, if not harsh reply! I'm finding it difficult to find any helpful material on java database connections

Comment: @Jonesy: duffymo's points are all very valid. You mentioned that you're new to Java, so I'd suggest you don't take his comments too seriously (read negatively) at the moment, although whatever he mentioned are best practices which you should adopt along your learning path.

Comment: Jonesy, it seemed to me that you were still thinking that the code you posted was good.  Don't take it personally - I don't know anything about you except the code you posted.  I just think it's the wrong thing to do, and I want to be clear about it.

Comment: So why was this downvoted four years after the fact?  AFTER it was accepted by the OP and upvoted four times?  Do people really go around seeking someone out to downvote?  I'd love it if a moderator would look into this.  It's unfair.

Comment: I suppose it must've offended the guy who asked the question. This is a proper answer and a brutal truth. This is proper way to write a Database class.. It's like the ezSQL (the PHP db class) for Java!

Comment: More likely that the guy who asked the question (and accepted the answer) is long gone.  The downvote came from some self-absorbed eejit.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `DriverManager.getConnection` returns a `java.sql.Connection`.  Since your class is also called Connection you are getting a name clash between `lokate.Connection` and `java.sql.Connection`.  You Will need to specify the fully qualified class name where ever you want to use `java.sql.Connection`, otherwise `lokate.Connection` is assumed.

Specify fully qualified class name like so:

```
java.sql.Connection con = null;
// ....
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Alternatively, rename your `Connection` class to something else and you will not get this naming conflict.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection` is an existing type in the `java.sql` package, which is what `DriverManager.getConnection` returns. You have named your class as `Connection` too, so this is causing the confusion. The simplest way out would be to rename your class to something else and add an `import java.sql.Connection;` at the top.

Comment: Would you say my method of having a connection class is the correct way to go about using databases?

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is it best practice to put the connection in the class like this then call a new object every time I want to do something with the db?

I think the best practice would be to use an existing solution to this problem, so that you can avoid re-inventing the wheel and focus on what makes your problem unique.

If you are writing a server application (it isn't clear whether you are), then I would also consider using a database connection pool.  Creating new database connections on the fly is not efficient and doesn't scale well.  You can read about database connection issues in [this article I wrote a while](http://innolitics.com/10x/database-pools/) back.