# Do i have to connect to database for each query?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I use the following codes to connect to Oracle's database:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;
String jdbc_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521:XE";
String query = "";
try {
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url);
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   query = "select username " + " from users ";
   rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

   // my codes

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
   System.out.println("result error, " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

} finally {
   try {
      rset.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error in closing " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Do I have to use this code in every action that I make for every query that I want? Making the connection and terminating it? Everytime?

Comment: Is this server-side or a client-side code?

Comment: I recommend you better to use a connection pool. The Oracle driver has a pool of connections you can use. On the other hand, you can implement shared static variable of this datasource or use the Singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to connect every time. Just make sure you close the resultset and the statement every time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3507846/575376) as example for a good DB wrapper class.

You can make your `Connection` a class variable that is initalized in the constructor. Something like this:

```
public class DbWrapper {
    private Connection conn = null;
    String jdbc_url="jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@localhost:1521:XE";

    public DbWrapper() {
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url);
    }

    public Arraylist<User> getUsers() {
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use pooled connections/ DataSource.

One DataSource instance is one unit of work and should be closed when the unit of work is finished (but note that it won't close the db connection if you're using pooled connections).

Also consider to use the higher-level JPA.

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs on a server such as Tomcat, GlassFish, best way is to use [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/) to get a connection. Otherwise, since you are using the Oracle JDBC driver, you could use the class [`OracleDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html).

For the getting the `Connection` object, you could implement the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). A simple way is using [Java enumerations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
enum DBEnum {
    ORACLE_XE {
        private DataSource ds = initDataSource();
        private DataSource initDataSource() {
            try {
                OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
                ds.setDriverType("thin");
                ds.setServerName("localhost");
                ds.setPortNumber(1521);
                ds.setDatabaseName("XE"); // Oracle SID
                ds.setUser("Herong");
                ds.setPassword("TopSecret");
                return ds;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            return ds.getConnection();
        }
    };
    public abstract Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;
}
```

And with this you would change your code:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;
String query = "";
try {
   conn = DBEnum.ORACLE_XE.getConnection();
   stmt = conn.createStatement();
   query = "select username " + " from users ";
   rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

   // my codes

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
   System.out.println("result error, " + e.getMessage());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

} finally {
   try {
      rset.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error in closing " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```